# delay slick slider until get response from calling API

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, delay, slick.js

I am using slick slider it is worked fine but after calling API request the slider apply first before the response of API
this is my  first function

```
fetchProducts () {
                this.getProducts ().then(response => {
                    const products = response.data.data;
                    this.products = products;
                    /* console.log(this.products); */
                    let element = document.getElementById("sliderContainer");
                    element.classList.add("regular");
                    this.apllySlider();

                })
            },
```

and this is apply slider function

```
            applySlider() {
                if (this.products.length >= 1) {
                    $(".regular").slick({
                        //dots: true,
                        infinite: true,
                        slidesToShow: 4,
                        slidesToScroll: 4,
                        responsive: [
                            {
                            breakpoint: 992,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                                slidesToScroll: 3,
                                infinite: true,
                                dots: true,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            breakpoint: 768,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                                slidesToScroll: 2,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            breakpoint: 480,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                                slidesToScroll: 2,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                } 
            }
```

how can i fix this problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just check the variable(which you assigning after getting a response) is null or not null

eg:

```
 applySlider() {
             if(this.products){
                if (this.products.length >= 1) {
                    $(".regular").slick({
                        //dots: true,
                        infinite: true,
                        slidesToShow: 4,
                        slidesToScroll: 4,
                        responsive: [
                            {
                            breakpoint: 992,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                                slidesToScroll: 3,
                                infinite: true,
                                dots: true,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            breakpoint: 768,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                                slidesToScroll: 2,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            breakpoint: 480,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                                slidesToScroll: 2,
                                arrows:false,
                            }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                } 
            }
         }
```